# What's the time complexity of query a node in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, time-complexity, cypher

I'm confused how neo4j query work.

If I have 10 nodes in my graph DB (7 Customer nodes + 3 Product nodes)

Now, I want to query a customer node(ex: C1), what's the time complexity?

And how the query work ? Like hash table O(1)? Or like binary search O(logN) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Example

```
MATCH (p:Person {name: 'Tom Hanks'})
RETURN p
```

#### Result

```
Planner COST

Runtime PIPELINED

Runtime version 5.8

Batch size 128

+------------------+----+------------------------+----------------+------+---------+----------------+------------------------+-----------+---------------------+
| Operator         | Id | Details                | Estimated Rows | Rows | DB Hits | Memory (Bytes) | Page Cache Hits/Misses | Time (ms) | Pipeline            |
+------------------+----+------------------------+----------------+------+---------+----------------+------------------------+-----------+---------------------+
| +ProduceResults  |  0 | p                      |              6 |    1 |       3 |                |                        |           |                     |
| |                +----+------------------------+----------------+------+---------+----------------+                        |           |                     |
| +Filter          |  1 | p.name = $autostring_0 |              6 |    1 |     250 |                |                        |           |                     |
| |                +----+------------------------+----------------+------+---------+----------------+                        |           |                     |
| +NodeByLabelScan |  2 | p:Person               |            125 |  125 |     126 |            120 |                    3/0 |     0.772 | Fused in Pipeline 0 |
+------------------+----+------------------------+----------------+------+---------+----------------+------------------------+-----------+---------------------+

Total database accesses: 379, total allocated memory: 184

1 row
```

As you can see, when you search a node, it will scan all nodes which mean the time complexity is O(N).

However you can create index for node that can improve search faster.

More info: [document](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/basic-example/)